# Storing Files Name in String Array

Tags: c#, file, nullreferenceexception

I wrote the following code to store files name in string array:

```
string[] fileStore;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\data\");
    FileInfo[] files = dir1.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (FileInfo f in files)
    {
        int a = 0;
        string ss;
        ss = f.Name;

        try
        {
            fileStore[a] = ss.ToString();
            a++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But this code gives the Following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Error also points to a particular line PS: `ss` is already a string, there is no reason to call `.ToString()`

Comment: So what did you try to resolve this problem?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: yes Sir it is null...

Comment: ... and that's the actual problem

Comment: @usr: i tried to convert string to string array but did solved..

Answer (score 4):

`filestore` is null. You can initalize it with `filestore = new string[files.Length]`.

Personally I'd replace your whole `foreach` loop by `filestore = files.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray()`.

Your `try...catch` is also nonsensical. There should never be an exception in the `try` part, unless your program has a bug. If you want a `try...catch` it should be around the file enumeration, and it should only catch a few IO related exceptions, not `System.Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring array `string[]` you have to know the exact size before allocating data with:

```
fileStore = filestore = new string[files.Length];
```

But maybe you could replace `string[]` with [`System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which doesn't require you to know the size of array in advance:

```
List<string> fileStore = null;

// In function:
if( fileStore == null){
    fileStore = new List<string>();
} else {
    fileStore.Clear(); // Optionally remove elements collected so far
}

foreach (FileInfo f in files) {
     fileStore.add( f.Name.ToString());
}

// And you always can export list to array:
string filesStoreArray[] = fileStore.ToArray();
```